# OAuth 2.0 and Google Signin in .NET 5 (core)?

Tags: asp.net, oauth, oauth-2.0, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I can't find anything online that mimics Google sign-in for MVC 5 and below for implementation in MVC 6. Is it supported yet? I was using OWIN, but it appears that it is now obsolete in Core. Could anyone be so kind as to throw some links or info my way? I'm at a complete loss.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To setup Google Authentication in an ASP.net Core project do the following

- Add the nuget package **Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Google**

I.e. add the following line to your project.json

```
"Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Google": "1.0.0-rc1-final"
```

Next, go to your startup.cs and add the following to your Configure method

```
        app.UseGoogleAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.ClientId = "[YOUR APP CLIENT ID]";
            options.ClientSecret = "[YOUR APP SECRET]";
        });
```

**NOTE** - It is very important that you add the above code AFTER `app.UseIdentity();` and BEFORE `app.UseMVC()`

For instructions on how to Obtain your ClientID / Secret from google go to the following site: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project

I created a blog post detailing this out step by step
http://joeraio.com/using-google-authentication-with-asp-net-core-asp-net-5/

Comment: Thank you SO much. I was using OWIN in MVC 5, but the new framework and lack of OWIN just completely had me for a loss. I really appreciate the links and info. Thank you again, Joe!

Comment: Hey Joe, so I followed your guide to setup Google sign-in and it works flawlessly. However, I'm a little bit confused on how to get claims. In MVC 5, you would declare the Provider and just do Identity.AddClaim("..."), but that doesn't seem to be the case in the new .NET. Do you have any idea? I cannot find anything online.

Comment: As of RC2 the package you need to references is "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google": "1.0.0-rc2-final" and the code in your configure file now looks like app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOptions
            {
                ClientId = "[YOUR APP CLIENT ID]",
                ClientSecret = "[YOUR APP SECRET]"
            });

Answer (score 0):

In .NET 5 is as follows:

First add nuget package:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google -Version 5.0.14
```

Then add this code to startup.cs:

```
services.AddAuthentication().AddGoogle(options =>
             {
                 options.ClientId = "xxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com";
                 options.ClientSecret = "yyyyyy-yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy";
             });
```

[microsoft reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/google-logins?view=aspnetcore-6.0#configure-google-authentication)